# Create temporary rows in mysql

Tags: php, actionscript-3

Well, I want to do a Flash AS3 Chat.

When the user send a message, the message will be created as a row in mysql with PHP, but if it be so, the mysql server will be very busy, then the row must be temporary.

Someone can help me? ^^' Thanks and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary rows will not solve the problem with your MySQL server being too busy. MySQL can handle many (e.g. tens of thousands) transactions per second with a pretty normal setup. [This article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2010/02/28/maximal-write-througput-in-mysql/) discusses quite a few of the parameters you might be interested in. So, that said, unless you have a TON of traffic on your chat system (and, I mean TONS and TONS) you will probably be ok just using MySQL, saving your rows, fetching your needed rows, and maybe writing a script to purge old rows after a certain date/time.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh! Thanks. I thought the mysql could be slow after this. Your reply was very helpful! I got it all what you said, when being mysql so, it still continue your works. And same so, can I create temporary tables to users mute?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're asking if you can create temporary tables for users. I would suggest that you don't create tables for users, but, rather create a "users table" with an ID field. Then, use that user_id in your messages table to figure out which user it belongs to. Then, you can adjust a status field in the users table to determine if a user is on mute, deleted, or any other status you would like to set.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a shared hosting platform, you can make a cron that matches the time. For example;

```
$db->query("DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE `message_posted` < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)")
```

This will delete all the rows with a time two hours more than the current time.

Change the interval for your preference.

Comment: So, after 2 hours, it would delete all of the rows?